# Finding the status of an Execute Javascript $( )

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
Execute Javascript  $('*:contains("Success"))
```

Is there a way to find out if this statement was successful? Can we return something into a variable and check the value of the variable?

Like for example

```
${var1} = Execute Javascript  $( )
if ${var1} = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the SeleniumLibrary, then [it uses Selenium RC](http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.9.1), not Selenium WebDriver (as you initally tagged your question).

Therefore, yes, [Selenium RC's `getEval()` method returns a `String`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#RBBeHyUmsSg/src/SeleniumLibrary/javascript.py&q=execute%20javascript%20package%3arobotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com&l=22), so you [will be able to return `String` values from your scripts](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html#selenium.selenium.selenium.get_eval), but nothing more:

> Gets the result of evaluating the specified JavaScript snippet. The
>   snippet may have multiple lines, but only the result of the last line
>   will be returned.

No need for a `return` statement in your JavaScript snippet, the last line is always returned.

---

If you're using Selenium2Library, then yeah, sure, even [the docs say so](http://rtomac.github.com/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript)!

It internally uses the WebDriver's [`executeScript()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) which says this:

> If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains a return
>   statement), then the following steps will be taken:
>
> - For an HTML element, this method returns a `WebElement`
> - For a decimal, a `Double` is returned
> - For a non-decimal number, a `Long` is returned
> - For a boolean, a `Boolean` is returned
> - For all other cases, a `String` is returned.
> - For an array, return a `List<Object>` with each object following the rules above. We support nested lists.
> - Unless the value is `null` or there is no return value, in which `null` is returned

Comment: Edited my answer extensively after discovering the Selenium2Library which I had no idea it existed.

Comment: Ah! Thanks very much Slanec for the info